# Concatenating two strings cuts string

Tags: shell, string

I extract two numerical strings from a textfile and and want to combine them to create a new string. The new string will be a filename.

This is the textfile `dates.dat`:

```
378464,2015-01-31
1019348,2015-03-31
1019342,2015-03-31
1019347,2015-03-31
1019349,2015-05-11
```

My shell script:

```
while IFS=, read line
do
    IFS=',' read -r id date <<< "$line"
    filename="${date}-${id}.xml"
    echo $filename
done < "dates.dat"
```

All I see is `3784641-31 1019348-31 1019342-31 1019347-31 1019349-11`. But I expect `2015-01-31-378464.xml` etc.

Comment: strange, tried here and looks ok (./script.sh -> 2015-01-31-378464.xml). Maybe some issue with formating dates.dat?

Comment: it works as expected on both ubuntu and solaris, I don't see the need for double read though.

Comment: what shell are you using?

Comment: Oh indeed, the problem was with the file. My colleague saved it on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you just want to replace the comma in the input with a dash, swap the two fields and add `.xml` at the end.  This is easily done using `awk`:

```
$ awk -v FS=',' -v OFS='-' '{ print $2, $1 ".xml" }' dates
2015-01-31-378464.xml
2015-03-31-1019348.xml
2015-03-31-1019342.xml
2015-03-31-1019347.xml
2015-05-11-1019349.xml
```

If your input file has DOS line-endings, send the input through `tr` first:

```
$ tr -d '\r' <dates | awk -v FS=',' -v OFS='-' '{ print $2, $1 ".xml" }'
```